# select all rows in two tables without a foreign key property

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables in a database, say, `cars` and `bikes`. They both have just two columns `id` and `name` like so:

```
Bikes table(BikeID int, BikeName)
Cars Table(CarId int, CarName)
```

These two tables have absolutely no physical relationship, (no foreign keys etc) no primary keys, its really just a column of values.

I want to select all rows from both tables. But if they have common names, I want to combine them, like so:

````````````````````````````````
Name        BikeId        CarId
```````````````````````````````
Car1         null         1
Car2         null         2
Bike1        1            null
Bike2        2            null
BikeCar      3            5
````````````````````````````````

Is it even possible to do this? 
I am using tsql (Sql server 2008)

thanks.

ps: I can think of making two tmp tables, adding values, make a third temp table, use a while loop and check for each product etc.. but I am just wondering if there is a shorter way of doing it... thanks.

edit: I realized I had typed the question without thinking too much. changed. thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contrary to the post title, this can be done using a join.  The FULL OUTER JOIN will return all results from both of the tables joined together where possible but if the join criteria is not matched it will return NULL for the other table columns (similar to doing both a left and a right outer join at the same time).

```
SELECT
    ISNULL(Bikes.BikeName, Cars.CarName) AS Name,
    Bikes.BikeId,
    Cars.CarId
FROM Bikes
    FULL OUTER JOIN Cars ON Bikes.BikeName = Cars.CarName
ORDER BY ISNULL(Bikes.BikeName, Cars.CarName)
```

Comment: Much better than my answer.  Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Amazing, works perfectly. thanks. This I dont want (i mean, my next question) but is it possible to put that in a view?

Comment: also, thanks for pointing out this can be done via join, edited my question.

Comment: @LocustHorde - Yes you can put this in a view; However you should remove the `ORDER BY` clause in the view (see note here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, using a FULL OUTER JOIN : documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187518.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
select BikeName as Name, BikeID, null as CarID from Bikes
union all
select CarName as Name, null as BikeID, CarID from Cars
```

Should do it for you.

Comment: Does that cover the last row in the example?  Cool if so.

Comment: Ah, didn't spot that! No, it doesn't solve the last one, missed that... ooops.

Comment: Hi, sorry, its doing something like selecting them independently, but just appending them!

Answer (score 0):

Try :-

```
SELECT 
  Name, MAX(BikeId) AS BikeId, MAX(CarId) AS CarId
FROM
(
   SELECT CarName AS Name, NULL AS BikeId, CarId FROM Cars
   UNION
   SELECT BikeName AS Name, BikeId, NULL AS CarId FROM Bikes
) vehicles
GROUP BY
  NAME
```

Comment: This works too; though not as neat as the FULL OUTER JOIN method perhaps.

Comment: I'm reading over the FULL OUTER JOIN stuff now.  Looks like a useful tool to have in one's arsenal.  It's faster than my solution too (just ran both just there then :D)

Comment: Hi, sorry, why are we using the max here?

Comment: The aggregation flattens rows, and is specifically included to flatten the last row in the your example.    In truth, MIN would have worked just as well. Having read Chris Shaffer's response though, full outer join much better.